# Автокодировщик для поиска аномальных числовых последовательностей

Tags: python

Есть последовательность чисел в несколько строк, представленная в CSV файле.

```
202 32 22 11 202 32 22 11 202 32 22 11 202 32 22 11 202 32 22 11 202 32 22 11 202 32 22 11 202 32 22 11
202 32 22 11 202 32 22 11 202 32 22 11 202 32 22 11 202 32 22 11 202 32 22 11 202 32 22 11 202 33 22 11
```

Хочу обучить модельку с использованием автокодировщика искать ошибку реконструкции в других таких строковых последовательностях.

```
203 32 22 11 202 32 22 11 202 32 22 11 202 32 22 11 202 32 22 11 202 32 22 11 202 32 22 11 202 32 22 11
202 32 22 11 202 32 22 11 202 32 22 11 202 32 22 11 202 32 22 11 202 32 22 11 202 32 22 11 202 33 22 13
```

Идея состоит в следующем, автокодировщик учится реконструировать каждую строку и пытается реконструировать строки проверочного файла.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers, models
import pandas as pd
# Load datasets
loadNormalData = "train.csv"
loadTestData = "test.csv"
normalData=pd.read_csv(loadNormalData)
testData=pd.read_csv(loadTestData)
print(normalData)
# Создание модели автокодировщика для обнаружения аномалий в числовых последовательностях
def build_autoencoder_model(input_dim):
    input_seq = layers.Input(shape=(input_dim,))
    encoded = layers.Dense(16, activation='relu')(input_seq)  # Размерность скрытого слоя можно настраивать
    decoded = layers.Dense(input_dim, activation='sigmoid')(encoded)
    autoencoder = models.Model(input_seq, decoded)
    autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')
    return autoencoder
input_dim = 32  # Пример: входные данные содержат 32 признаков
# Обучение модели на нормальных данных
autoencoder = build_autoencoder_model(input_dim)
autoencoder.fit(normalData, epochs=15, batch_size=32)
# Определение порога для обнаружения аномалий
decoded_data = autoencoder.predict(normalData)
mse = np.mean(np.power(normalData - decoded_data, 2), axis=1)
threshold = np.percentile(mse, 1)  # Пример: порог на уровне 100-го процентиля
# Оценка и обнаружение аномалий
decoded_normal_data = autoencoder.predict(testData)
mse_normal = np.mean(np.power(testData - decoded_normal_data, 2), axis=1)
anomalies_normal = testData[mse_normal > threshold]
decoded_anomalous_data = autoencoder.predict(test_anomalous_data)
mse_anomalous = np.mean(np.power(test_anomalous_data - decoded_anomalous_data, 2), axis=1)
anomalies_anomalous = test_anomalous_data[mse_anomalous > threshold]
if (anomalies_anomalous == True)
    print("Anomaly detection")
```

Столкнулся со следующей проблемой:

```
(base) qwerty@mk:~/proj/AE$ python3 AE.py
2023-12-07 17:59:33.344304: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:182] This TensorFlow     binary is optimized to use available CPU instructions in performance-critical operations.
To enable the following instructions: AVX2 FMA, in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the     appropriate compiler flags.
  202 32 22 13 202 32 22 11 202 32 22 11 202 32 22 11 202 32 22 11 202 32 22 11 202 32 22 11 202 32 22 11
0  202 32 22 11 202 32 22 11 202 32 22 11 202 32     ...                                                     
Epoch 1/15
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/qwerty/proj/AE/AE.py", line 22, in <module>
    autoencoder.fit(normalData, epochs=15, batch_size=32)
  File "/home/qwerty/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "/tmp/__autograph_generated_fileqibotr3o.py", line 15, in tf__train_function
    retval_ = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(step_function), (ag__.ld(self), ag__.ld(iterator)), None, fscope)
^^^^^
ValueError: in user code:

File "/home/qwerty/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 1401, in train_function  *
    return step_function(self, iterator)
File "/home/qwerty/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 1384, in step_function  **
    outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
File "/home/qwerty/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 1373, in run_step  **
    outputs = model.train_step(data)
File "/home/qwerty/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 1150, in train_step
    y_pred = self(x, training=True)
File "/home/qwerty/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
File "/home/qwerty/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/engine/input_spec.py", line 280, in assert_input_compatibility
    raise ValueError(

    ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer 'model' (type Functional).

Input 0 of layer "dense" is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 32, but received input with shape (None, 1)

Call arguments received by layer 'model' (type Functional):
• inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 1), dtype=string)
• training=True
• mask=None
```

Прошу помощи в доведении до ума данной программы.

Comment: А можно поподробнее написать, что таоке реконструкция и ошибка в реконструкции?